# Export Library.scpt: execution error: The variable ndx is not defined. (-2753) and it's on the same "local" line as two RECOGNIZED variables

Tags: applescript

Here is the relevant code: I **believe** the error is being generated in the "repeat" block at the end. The command line used to run the program is:  "osascript Export\ Library.scpt /Users/bryandunphy/Development/iTunesLibraryConsolidator Testing.xml".

```
on run (clp)
    if clp's length is not 2 then error "Incorrect Parameters"
    local destination, libraryName, ndx
    set destination to clp's item 1
    set libraryName to clp's item 2
    menuClick({"iTunes", "File", "Library", "Export Library…"})
    tell application "System Events" to set the value of text field "Save As:" of window "iTunes" of process "iTunes" to libraryName
    tell pop up button 1 of group 1 of window "iTunes" of process "iTunes" of application "System Events" to click
    ndx = 1
    repeat
        if the title of menu item ndx is "" then
            select menu item (ndx - 1)
            exit repeat
        else
            ndx = ndx + 1
        end if
    end repeat
    my switchDir(destination, "iTunes", "iTunes", true, false)
    tell button "Save" of window "iTunes" to click
    return (destination & "/" & libraryName & ".xml")
end run
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a language semantics confusion.

The `local` statement declares the variable but does not define (assign a value) it (like in C).

The statement

```
ndx = 1
```

compares (currently not defined) variable `ndx` with 1,

```
set ndx to 1
```

assignes value 1 to variable `ndx` (defines it).

Similarily

```
set ndx to ndx + 1
```

Further everything after the line `tell pop up button 1 ...` must be inside a `System Events` tell block

Comment: Please expand on "Further everything after the line tell pop up button 1 ... must be inside a System Events tell block." **EXACTLY*** which lines need to be inside the "tell block"?

Comment: Actually the two lines containing `menu item` and the line `tell button "Save" ...`